# Laravel 5.1 Format date BEFORE being put in array inside controller

Tags: php, date, laravel, controller, laravel-5.1

I have the following code in my controller:

```
$gecko_id = Gecko::where(compact('user_id', 'name'))->first()->id; 
$weight = Weight::where(compact('user_id', 'gecko_id'))->orderBy('weighed_date', 'desc')->take(7)->get()->reverse();
$gecko = Gecko::where(compact('user_id', 'name'))->first();

return view('gecko.show')
    ->with('gecko', $gecko)
    ->with('dates', $weight->lists('weighed_date'))
    ->with('amounts', $weight->lists('gecko_weight'));
```

Which is sending data to my view for a chart i'm plotting. My `dates` list is outputting the following data format:

```
["2015-06-01","2015-05-01","2015-04-01","2015-03-01","2015-02-01","2015-01-01"]
```

Ideally I would like to format this before it is passed to the view so it's more readable. So say `2015-06-01` would be be reformatted into `01/06/2016` - I know how to do this in the usual PHP way, but because I'm putting the data into an array, I'm unsure on the best way of achieving my goal.

Comment: @Uchiha `Syntax error, unexpected 'where' (T_STRING)` unfortunately

Comment: Sorry it should be like as `Weight::select("*",DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(dates,'%d/%m/%Y')) as reform_date"))->where(compact('user_id', 'gecko_id'))->orderBy('weighed_date', 'desc')->take(7)->get()->reverse();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can archive this by writing an accessor in your model. [Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).

For example:

```
class Weight extends Model{
    ...
    public function getWeighedDateAttribute($value){
        return Carbon\Carbon::parse($value)->format('d/m/y');
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: "The separation symbol could not be found
Trailing data"